# Where can i download the Kotlin Bom Jar Version 1.8.10

Tags: kotlin, maven, gradle, generics

i have been searching constantly for the kotlin-bom:1.8.10.jar but i cannot find it anywhere.

I have searched it more than weeks. I need the jar and i cannot find a download button anywhere to download it.

I tried downloading it with IntelliJ creating a Gradle project but it says Kotlin-Bom cannot be found in central but its fake. It can be found in central look:

https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-bom/1.9.10/versions

Please someone drop here the .jar file for the kotlin bom :(

- Tried downloading from IntelliJ project but it cannot be found in central, it says.

Answer (score 0):

BOM stands for Bill of Materials and is a POM file which specifies versions. The reason you can't find a JAR for it is that the POM is the entirety of the artifact and no JAR is required (there's no associated code). If you look in the Kotlin GitHub repository, you can see that the BOM code is that one POM file:   https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/tools/kotlin-bom

Gradle docs about BOM import:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:bom_import

> Gradle provides support for importing bill of materials (BOM) files, which are effectively .pom files that use  to control the dependency versions of direct and transitive dependencies. The BOM support in Gradle works similar to using import when depending on a BOM in Maven. In Gradle however, it is done via a regular dependency declaration on the BOM

So it seems that it's imported as if it's a JAR, but actually it isn't one.